Swift diacritic insensitive "contains()"?
I have an array of strings dictionaryStrings filled with Vietnamese phrases. When a user inputs a search word, I would like to see if that userInput is contained as a substring in any of the array elements. This works if user types the word with the correct Vietnamese diacritics/accent marks. (e.g. typing "chân" will match with one of the array elements "chân"). But I would also like it to match if user types simply "chan", and will match with "chân". I found in this answer that string.stringByFoldingWithOptions can remove diacritics. But after importing Foundation I still get Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByFoldingWithOptions' error. How can I do this with string.contains() ?
userInput = searchViewModel.text.lowercased()
                
if !userInput.isEmpty {
    filteredDictionary = dictionaryStrings.filter {
         $0.lowercased().contains(userInput)
    }
}


Note stringByFoldingWithOptions is an NSString method, not String — NSString and String are bridged, you can cast your string with as NSString if needed. Also in Swift the function's signature is folding(options:locale:)

I'm not familiar with folding(), but $0.range(of: userInput, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil might do the trick. I don't know what's dictionaryStrings really, but creating a folding version of its value might indeed increase the search/filter.

As others have said, the function stringByFoldingWithOptions. There are some "orphaned" functions in NSString that aren't available natively in the Swift String class, and some others (like this one) that have been renamed for Swift. If you can't find a given String function in the docs, it's worth trying to switch the help feature to search for Objective-C functions, and if you find it there, switch to Swift. The help system will frequently then show you the Swift version. I was able to find the Swift version of stringByFoldingWithOptions in the Xcode help system with that approach.

stringByFoldingWithOptions is a member of NSString in Objective-C.
For Swift, you may want to look into the equivalent folding method.
Some of the latest answers at the link you provided give examples on using folding(options:locale:):
func toNoSmartQuotes() -> String {
let userInput: String = self
return userInput.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)

}

Thank you. This was it:
$0.folding(options: String.CompareOptions.diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current).contains(userInput)
The word "folding" wasn't intuitive here so initially I overlooked it.
